# Logging data changes for synchronization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest, ruby-on-rails-4, synchronization

I am looking for solution of logging data changes for public API.

There is a need to tell client app which tables form db has changed and need to be synchronised since the app synchronised last time and also need to be for specific brand and country.

Current Solution:

- Version table with class_names of models which is touched from every model on create, delete, touch and save action.
- When we are touching version for specific model we also look at the reflected associations and touch them too.
- Version model is scoped to brand and country
- REST API is responding to a request that includes last_sync_at:timestamp, brand and country
- Rails look at Version with given attributes and return class_names of models which were changed since lans_sync_at timestamp.

This solution works but the problem is performance and is also hard to maintenance.

**UPDATE 1:**

Maybe the simple question is. 
**What is the best practice how to find out and tell frontend apps when and what needs to be synchronized. In terms of whole concept.**

**Conditions:**

- Front end apps needs to download only their own content changes not whole dataset.
- Does not invoked synchronization when application from different country or brand needs to be synchronized.

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is not quite clear (at least it isn't to me). Could you rephrase it/detail it to better explain what the issue is and what your expected result should be?

Comment: Implement change data capture if that helps...

Comment: @DeepakMishra what do you mean with "Implement change data capture" could you be more specific please.

Comment: I am not sure which database you are using?

Comment: If you are using mysql you can use this link http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63681/does-mysql-have-a-version-of-change-data-capture ...I am not sure of Ruby on Rails, I have seen your question when I was browsing for API tag.

Comment: I am using Postgresql. It will be great if it is possible to collect data changes on database layer. But some data changes are related to the brand and country entity and I think that could be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best solution would be to use redis (or some other key-value store) and save your information there. Writing to redis is much faster than any sql db. You can write some service class that would save the data like:

```
RegisterTableUpdate.set(table_name, country_id, brand_id, timestamp)
```

Such call would save given timestamp under key that could look like i.e. `table-update-1-1-users`, where first number is country id, second number is brand id, followed by table name (or you could use country and brand names if needed). If you would like to find out which tables have changed you would just need to find redis keys with query "table-update-1-1-*", iterate through them and check which are newer than timestamp sent through api.

It is worth to rmember that redis is not as reliable as sql databases. Its reliability depends on configuration so you might want to read [redis guidelines](http://redis.io/topics/persistence) and decide if you would like to go for it.

Comment: Redis is good idea but it solves only the data storage and of course performance but as you write problem is reliability. So I prefer the sql database storage. What I am looking for is alternative to whole concept of catching and logging data changes.

Comment: Can you write little bit more about how models are associated with brand and country (if there is any association at all)?

Comment: I need to sync many models. Some of them are common for all apps like Categories and some of them has relation to brand and country. For instance Recipe model which belongs to brand and has many countries. It has also many other associations like for instance ingredients. So when ingredients record has been updated I also have to touch related recipe for countries and brand but only for those which recipe is belongs to. It is hard to describe but hope it will helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the fact that ActiveModel automatically logs every time it updates a table row (the 'Updated at' column)

When checking what needs to be updated, select the objects you are interested in and compare their 'Updated at' with the timestamp from the client app

The advantage of this approach is that you don't need to keep an additional table that lists all the updates on models, which should speed things up for the API users and be easier to maintain.

The disadvantage is that you cannot see the changes in data over time, you only know that a change occurred and you can access the latest version. If you need to track changes in data over time efficiently, than I'm afraid you'll have to rework things from the top.

Answer (score 0):

(read last part - this is what you are interested in)
I would recommend that you use the decorator design pattern for changing the client queries. So the client sends a query of what he wants and the server decides what to give him based on the client's last update.

so:

1. the client sends a query that includes the time it last synched
2. the server sees the query and takes into account the client's nature (device-country)
3. the server decorates (changes accordingly) the query to request from the DB only the relevant data, and if that is not possible:
4. after the data are returned from the database manager they are trimmed to be relevant to where they are going
5. returns to the client all the new stuff that the client cares about.

I assume that you have a time entered field on your DB entries.
In that case the "decoration" of the query (abstractly) would be just to add something like a "WHERE" clause in your query and state you want data entered after the last update.

Finally, if you want that to be done for many devices/locales/whatever implement a decorator for the query and the result of the query and serve them to your clients as they should be served. (Keep in mind that in contrast with a subclassing approach you will only have to implement one decorator for each device/locale/whatever - not for all combinations!

Hope this helped!